# Clarification required against this piece of code in Java

Tags: java, file-handling

when I write this piece of

```
String path="d:\\test.txt";
    boolean chk;
    File f=new File(path);

    try
    {
        chk=f.createNewFile();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        chk=false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(chk)
        System.out.println("file created.");
    else
        System.out.println("file not created");
```

file is created in d-drive

but when I use this

```
String path="d:\\test.txt";
    File f=new File(path);

    if(f.createNewFile())
        System.out.println("file created.");
    else
        System.out.println("file not created");
```

it throws exception.

Please enlighten me on this

Comment: What's the exception being thrown? (post full details)

Comment: in Eclipse it shows "unhandled IOException"

Comment: what modifications need to be done in the 2nd piece of code to make it run successfuly??

Comment: That's not throwing an exception, that's the compiler telling you you haven't coded your program properly.

Comment: I have added code for you. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change second part of you code to following:

```
                    String path = "d:\\test.txt";
                    File f = new File(path);

                    try {
                        if (f.createNewFile())
                            System.out.println("file created.");
                        else
                            System.out.println("file not created");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

You are required to do this because if you don't surrond f.createNewFile() within try/catch block, your code won't compile. As usage of f.createNewFile() throws IOException you need to either put it in try/catch block catching IOException or method using this part of code needs to declare throws IOException.

Comment: dude I guess this is what I did in first snippet :-)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that the second piece of code actually "throws an exception"; most likely what you are seeing is a compile error warning you that you must catch the checked exception `IOException` when you call `createNewFile`.

A "checked" exception *must* have a handler or be declared by the calling method via `throws`, or your code will not compile.  `IOException` is checked.  `createNewFile` declares that it `throws IOException`.  Therefore your second block of code is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

File.createNewFile() throws an exception if the file already exists (or you don't have the right to create the file). So after running the first piece of code... the second will fail, if you forgot to delete test.txt.

Comment: Sir I guess in that  case o/p will be  "File not created."
But the code will surely run.

Comment: It will only run if it compiles, and your second example doesn't compile.

Comment: @Ankit @EJP some IDE's have a configuration setting which allows you to run the code anyway in spite of compilation errors (the red marks). Truly the code won't always run successfully due to compilation errors. @Ankit: you need to ensure that you get rid of red marks before you run the code in Eclipse. They are not for decoration :) Click the bullets for a list of possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you get an IO exception or you cannot create (write) that file, maybe because it's opened.